# Which ID to be used to validate user request? ID Token or Access Token - AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement a Single Page Application, while using AWS Cognito as IdP. I am planning to have a Node server connected to MongoDB. MEAN stack basically.

**My application structure**:

I selected `Implicit Grant` OAuth Flows option in the *App Client settings* for the *User Pool*.

`Email` and `OpenID` for the Allowed OAuth Scopes.

Home page (Login / Register) --> AWS Cognito SignIn / SignUp --> Callback URL [containing `id_token`, `access_token`, `expires_in` and `token_type`] --> API Server

**Understanding**:

Using the decoding techniques mentioned in the docs, I guess I should be able to validate that the `access_token` is *Valid* and it belongs to my user-pool.

Using the `id_token`, I guess I should be able to retrieve the user record.

**Question**

*How an API request with a valid token can be restricted from seeing any other user's detail?*

**Trials**:

- Design the API in such a way that it does not expect *Query Params* and it uses ONLY the token sent for every API request to retrieve the corresponding user record.

**Clarification needed**:

- Do I have to send the `id_token` and `access_token` from my UI to the API Server for every API request, or should a single token be enough? Which one should that be?
- Does my API Server have to connect to AWS Cognito for every API call to check if the token is valid at their end too, or to get the `attributes` from the *user-pool* using that token?

Comment: You can find the answer to the first question here https://web-identity-federation-playground.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **the ID token**. Check out the [Using the ID Token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token) docs.

> The ID token is a JSON Web Token (JWT) that contains claims about the identity of the authenticated user [...] You can use this identity information inside your application. The ID token can also be used to authenticate users against your resource servers or server applications.

Longer answer: while the ID token is the way to go if you want to handle all authorization yourself (i.e. your backend uses the ID token to decide what resources a given user is allowed to access), you could also use a [Congito ID Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html) to perform authorization. I.e., convert the User Pool credentials you have right now to AWS IAM credentials. The IAM role backing this can be user-specific, by [using the current user's Cognito sub ID in the role policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html).